# Returned type in operator overloading

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading

Suppose to have the following class definition:

```
template <typename T> class Foo {
public:
    T x;
    Foo(T x): {x = 1;}
}
```

And to overload the following functions:

```
// function 1
Foo<T> operator*(T s) const {
    return Foo<T>(x*s);
}

// function 2
Foo<T> &operator*=(T s) {
    x *= s;
    return *this;
}
```

Now, i instantiate an object:

```
Foo<float> foo;
float y = 2.2;
```

Then, the binary operator `foo * y` returns an object of type`Foo<float>` because `y` is `float`. If instead `y` were of type `int`, `foo * y` would return an object of type `Foo<int>` because `y` is an `int`. In this case, even though `x*s` returns a `float`, it would be casted to `int` by the constructor.

**Conclusion**: `bar` is of type `Foo<T>` where `T` is the type of the scalar I'm multiplying foo by.

---

Now, consider the assignment operator `*=`. Then, `foo *= y` returns a reference to `foo`.

**Conclusion**: whatever is the type of `y`, `foo` will still be of type
 `Foo<float>`.

Can you please correct me if I'm wrong? Also, what if i write:

```
Foo<int> foo;
float y = 2.2;
```

the argument `y` is downcasted to `int` before being passed to function 1 & 2?

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding templates. The multiplication operator return `Foo<float>` (in the first example) because the template type `T` is `float`. If `foo` is `Foo<float>` then doing `foo * 1` will convert the `int` value `1` to the `float` value `1.0f` for the call.

Comment: hmm right. Indeed I was a bit confused by the function declaration. I thought that the   `T s` took the type of `s` and therefore that the function returned a `Foo<T>` with `T` type of `s`. Instead, `T` always refers to the generic type of the class, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct.